# Converting a dataframe into dict values with duplicate keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this

```
   col1   col2    col3  col4   action_id
0   1      2        2     0       a, apple
1   1      2        3     5       b, apple
2   0.2   0.3       8     1       c, apple
3   0.2   0.02      1     2       a, apple
4   11     11       22    11      b, apple
```

I want to convert this data frame into dict with action_id as my key and others as my values.

I want my output in this manner:

```
{(1, 'a', 'apple'): array([[1, 2, 2, 0]]),
(1, 'b', 'apple'): array([[1, 2, 3, 5]]),
(1, 'c', 'apple'): array([[0.2, 0.3, 8, 1]]),
(2, 'a', 'apple'): array([[0.2, 0.02, 1, 2]]),
(2, 'b', 'apple'): array([[11, 11, 22, 11]])}
```

I have tried this method

`data2d = var.set_index('action_id').T.to_dict('list')` considering `var` as my dataframe.

But this method is overwriting the values in dict with the duplicate keys and only returns me the last values from the duplicate key. Is there any way I can get duplicate keys also with different values?

```
{('c', 'apple'): array([[0.2, 0.3, 8, 1]]),
('a', 'apple'): array([[0.2, 0.02, 1, 2]]),
('b', 'apple'): array([[11, 11, 22, 11]])}
```

**Edit**

I did a little change and added 1 more element to my `action_id` and now my frame looks like this:

```
   col1   col2    col3  col4   action_id
0   1      2        2     0       1, a, apple
1   1      2        3     5       1, b, apple
2   0.2   0.3       8     1       1, c, apple
3   0.2   0.02      1     2       2, a, apple
4   11     11       22    11      2, b, apple
```

but still, I am getting the same issue as only my last values are coming

```
{(1, 'c', 'apple'): array([[0.2, 0.3, 8, 1]]),
(2, 'a', 'apple'): array([[0.2, 0.02, 1, 2]]),
(2, 'b', 'apple'): array([[11, 11, 22, 11]])}
```

Comment: This is **impossible**, dictionaries cannot have duplicated keys. You must find another output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to have duplicated keys in a python dictionary.

If you want, you can aggregate at the list/array level:

```
var.set_index('action_id').groupby(level=0).agg(list).T.to_dict('list')
```

Output:

```
{('a', 'apple'): [[1.0, 0.2], [2.0, 0.02], [2, 1], [0, 2]],
 ('b', 'apple'): [[1.0, 11.0], [2.0, 11.0], [3, 22], [5, 11]],
 ('c', 'apple'): [[0.2], [0.3], [8], [1]]}
```

Or:

```
var.set_index('action_id').groupby(level=0).apply(lambda g: g.to_numpy()).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{('a', 'apple'): array([[1.  , 2.  , 2.  , 0.  ],
                        [0.2 , 0.02, 1.  , 2.  ]]),
 ('b', 'apple'): array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  5.],
                        [11., 11., 22., 11.]]),
 ('c', 'apple'): array([[0.2, 0.3, 8. , 1. ]])}
```

Comment: The way you have shown may work but it will cause me a mismatch of the arrays as this has to further go through the ML training where values and keys will be used for training. So I need new key pair every time a duplicate key also arrives so that it will have an equal size of an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
k=df1.action_id.str.split(",").map(tuple)
v=df1.loc[:,:'col4'].apply(lambda ss:ss.to_numpy(),axis=1)
dict(zip(k,v))
    
 out：
    
{('a', ' apple'): array([0.2 , 0.02, 1.  , 2.  ]),
 ('b', ' apple'): array([11., 11., 22., 11.]),
 ('c', ' apple'): array([0.2, 0.3, 8. , 1. ])}
```